# Wanted: example(s) of PEG Grammar for deeply nested Python boolean expressions

Tags: python, boolean-expression, peg

I would like an example of a PEG grammar for deeply nested Python boolean expressions. The PEG grammar can't be "very recursive" or this will lead to stack overflow. Support for '|', '&', '(' and ')' required.

Example of input: (a=1|b=1|c=1|d=1&e=2)&(f=2&g=2&h=2|i=3|j=3|k=3)

Answer (score 3):

To parse typical (especially Boolean logic) expressions, you hardly need a Peg parser; there's never really a need to backtrack.  Pick any parsing engine and use it (including a Peg engine if you insist).

Here's a grammar that will work for your example:

```
EXPRESSION = DISJUNCTION ;
DISJUNCTION = CONJUNCTION ( '|' CONJUNCTION )*;
CONJUNCTION = TERM ( '&' TERM );
TERM = '~' TERM | '(' EXPRESSION ')' | CONDITION ;
CONDITION = VARIABLE '=' CONSTANT ;
```

If you want to implement this grammar using a hand-written, recursive descent parser that is easy to code, see my SO answer on how to do this: [Is there an alternative for flex/bison that is usable on 8-bit embedded systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769)

Regarding overflowing the stack:  unless your expression is nested hundreds of levels ("parentheses") deep, on most windows or linux system, the available stack is far bigger than the stack demands of a parser applied to expressions that people write in practice.  With huge expressions, pretty much people can't read them anyway so they don't occur.  OP's example expression requires nesting of just a few stack entries.

If you write a grammar for a full-fledged programming language, and somebody writes a big, complex program in that langauge, you might risk overflowing the stack.  I can tell you from experience with a compiler I built that a nesting of  256 (stack frames) fits easily in Windows 1Mb stack space, and that's enough to compile 2 million line program with every strange construct and deeply nested lexical scoping stunt known to mankind in it.

Comment: Hi Ira. Thanks for the great answer :) I actually need a PEG grammar to feed to a parser generator. What I meant by "nested" was that the grammar should ideally not create a binary tree - this leads to a very deep tree if the expression has many many ORs and ANDs. The grammar I have is right recursive (I think that's the proper term) and leads to stack overflow for very long expressions (even without parenthesis): https://github.com/kschiess/parslet/blob/master/example/boolean_algebra.rb

Comment: Thanks Ira. I've given up on using a PEG-grammar-to-parser-generator, because of the lack of debug support. I think I will go for your hand written approach! :)

Comment: @SoupMonster:  (Yeah, I know this response is a "little" delayed...)    Your grammar will be left or right recursive  pretty much whereever you have protductions that process a list of items (e.g.,  AND ... and OR ...).   While the parser will process the productions and perhaps left/right recurse deeply, it isn't that hard to get generate a "list" node for AND and a list node for "OR" ... so your AND/OR trees can be relatively shallow.   I frankly don't understand how you can run out of stack space for any realistic expressions typed by people.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PEG grammar that supports the simple boolean expression you have above (and a little more), with the assumption that AND should bind more tightly than OR:

```regex
expr       = multiOR !.
multiOR    = multiAND (_wsp opOR _wsp multiAND)*
multiAND   = comparison (_wsp opAND _wsp comparison)*

comparison = varOrNum _wsp opCOMP _wsp varOrNum
             / '!'? var
             / '!'? '(' multiOR ')'

varOrNum   = var / num

var        = [a-z]i [a-z0-9_]i*
num        = '-'? [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?

opOR       = '|' '|'?
opAND      = '&' '&'?
opCOMP     = [<>=] '='? / [≤≥≠] / '!='

_wsp       = [ \t]*
```

Here you can see the result of applying this PEG to input like yours:

[image: Screenshot of http://phrogz.net/js/pegsh using this grammar with highlighted output]

Obviously the comparison operators are a little overboard, and it supports both `|`/`&` and `||`/`&&` for the boolean operators. Feel free to modify as desired.